# Quartz.net transactions?

Tags: quartz.net

Is there a way to control the transactions used by Quartz.net?

We use Quartz to schedule jobs, but we keep metadata about the jobs in a separate table in a more readable format for the UI. Obviously it would be bad if the network failed right after the quartz job was scheduled but before we could write the metadata to the other table. I'd like to wrap everything up in a transaction but I don't know how to get quartz to use it. Is this supported?

Comment: what do you mean saying `wrap everything up in a transaction`?

Comment: Maybe you should just utilize JobDataMap for trigger or job to store the metadata?

Comment: @Backs I'd like quartz to use a transaction to write to the quartz db, and then give me that transaction so I can use it to write the metadata to a different table in the same db. I want everything to commit atomically so I don't end up with one table written and another failed.

Comment: @MarkoLahma We do use the JobDataMap for data that is needed for the job to run. The metadata I'm referring to is not needed for the job, it's simply a readable version that users can view on a web app. Users are allowed to schedule their own jobs, so rather than parse quartz's binary storage format, we store information about the jobs in a second table, so we can show for example "Job 1 - Runs Report 'Foo' Weekly on Monday at 12PM for User 'Bar'".